# Subclass of webapp.RequestHandler doesn't have a response attribute

Tags: python, google-app-engine, post-redirect-get

Using the below code, my template loads fine until I submit the from, then I get the following error:

```
e = AttributeError("'ToDo' object has no attribute 'response'",)
```

Why doesn't my `ToDo` object not have a `response` attribute? It works the first time it's called.

```
import cgi
import os 

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Task(db.Model):
    description = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    complete = db.BooleanProperty()

class ToDo(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        todo_query = Task.all()
        todos = todo_query.fetch(10)
        template_values = { 'todos': todos }

        self.renderPage('index.html', template_values)

    def renderPage(self, filename, values):
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, values))          


class UpdateList(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        todo = ToDo()
        todo.description = self.request.get('description')
        todo.put()
        self.redirect('/')

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/', ToDo), 
                                      ('/add', UpdateList)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
  run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Here's the template code so far, I'm just listing the descriptions for now.

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en">
<html>
 <head>
    <title>ToDo tutorial</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div>
    {% for todo in todos %}
        <em>{{ todo.description|escape }}</em>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <h3>Add item</h3>
    <form action="/add" method="post">
        <label for="description">Description:</label>
        <input type="text" id="description" name="description" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add Item" />
    </form> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why do you do what you do in `post`? it should be:

```
def post(self):
    task = Task()                # not ToDo()
    task.description = self.request.get('description')
    task.put()
    self.redirect('/')
```

`put` called on a subclass of `webapp.RequestHandler` will [try to handle PUT request, according to docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requesthandlerclass.html#RequestHandler_put).

Comment: *slaps forehead* - sometimes you can't see the woods for the trees. Yeah, it should have been that. Thanks SilentGhost.